# Getting the visible text in a JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I have a JeditorPane in a JScrollPane.   At certain points in the application, I would like to retrieve the text that is visible in the scrollPane (the text that is currently showing) and only this text.    Is there a way to do this?

Thank you,

Elliott

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the viewport to get the view position and size.

```
JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport();
Point startPoint = viewport.getViewPosition();
Dimension size = viewport.getExtentSize();
Point endPoint = new Point(startPoint.x + size.width, startPoint.y + size.height);
```

Once you know the start/end points of the viewport you can use:

```
int start = editorPane.viewToModel( startPoint );
int end = editorPane.viewToModel( endPoint );
```

Once you know the offsets of the text you want you can get the text from the component:

```
String text = editorPane.getText(start, end - start);
```

None of the code is tested.

Comment: I can't tell you how long I've been trying to figure this out!.   This is brilliant.   Thank you!